# C# trouble in visual studio, can't get button click to execute lines properly

Tags: c#

I am having some trouble with my code

The problem is every time I press the done button nothing calculates 
I am using visual studio to code in C#

```
        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Variable declaration
            int Numtckets;
            int NumberofULT = 35;
            int NumberofSLT = 55;
            int NumberofEZT = 42;
            int Total = 0;

            //Get input
            Numtckets = int.Parse(Numberoftickesearned.Text);
            //Processing
            if (RADULT.Checked == true) 
            {
                Total = NumberofULT * Numtckets;
                TotalLbl.Text = "Your total is..." + Total;
            }
            else if (RADSLT.Checked == true)
            {
                Total = NumberofSLT * Numtckets;
                TotalLbl.Text = "Your total is..." + Total;
            }
            else if (RADEZT.Checked == true)
            {
                Total = NumberofEZT * Numtckets;
                TotalLbl.Text = "Your total is..." + Total;
            }
            else if (RADULT.Checked == false && RADSLT.Checked == false && RADEZT.Checked == false)
            { 
                TotalLbl.Text = "Please enter the number of tickets" + Total;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I've tried editing the name properties and such with no luck. After I did that I still haven't gotten any results, any help would be appriecated.

Comment: This event handler seems to be connected to a label, not a button... Are you sure you are clicking `label1`?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize until you pointed it out.